# Ruby Replacing Parts of String

Tags: ruby, string

I have this String

```
s = "03:23 PM on 09/04/12"
```

I want to take out the ' on ' and replace it with just a space ' '.  I thought the string's gsub method, along with regex, would be the best solution.  I am just not sure why this wont work.

```
s ="03:23 PM on 09/04/12"
s.gsub(/ on /, ' ')
puts s
#=> "03:23 PM on 09/04/12"
```

Comment: `gsub` returns the changed string, `gsub!` will mutate the string in place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A string's `gsub` method *returns* the modified string and leaves the object string alone. If you want to modify the object in-place then you have to use `gsub!`.

Also, if you want to change only one occurrence then `sub` is probably your best bet.

So

```
s = "03:23 PM on 09/04/12"

s = s.sub(' on ', ' ')
```

or

```
s.sub!(' on', ' ')
```

Comment: `sub`, because it changes the first occurence, can be much faster than `gsub` when dealing with long strings. `sub` will exit immediately and `gsub` will scan the remaining string for addition targets to replace.

Comment: @theTinMan: To be fair, the advantage is very unlikely to be significant, especially on twenty-character strings.

Comment: As I said, it affects long strings especially when dealing with many of them.

Answer (score 2):

works fine for me... Perhaps you meant to use `gsub!`?

```
>> s ="03:23 PM on 09/04/12"
=> "03:23 PM on 09/04/12"
>> s.gsub(/ on /, ' ')
=> "03:23 PM 09/04/12"
>> s.gsub!(/ on /, ' ')
=> "03:23 PM 09/04/12"
>> s
=> "03:23 PM 09/04/12"
```

Answer (score 2):

You are not required to use a Regexp object for the gsub parameter (`/ on /`)  you can also use a string - this worked for me!

```
s = "03:23 PM on 09/04/12"

p s.gsub " on ", " "
#=> "03:23 PM 09/04/12"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
s ="03:23 PM on 09/04/12"
s.gsub(' on ', ' ')
#>> "03:23 PM 09/04/12"
```

You can go without `regex` in this case,but if you want to use `regex`,then use `s.gsub!(/ on /, ' ')`